# Which is better practice for setting state in react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am learning Redux. I am kind of new so I dont want to develop a bad habit at the start which is why i am writing this.

The doc i am reading says that in the reducers we need to always set the state where we change it - in other words do the following:

```
const someReducer = (state=initState, {type, payload}) => {
    switch(type) {
        case 'CHANGE_VALUE_ONE' : {
            state = {...state, valueOne: payload }
            break
        }
        case 'CHANGE_VALUE_TWO' : {
            state = {...state, valueTwo: payload }
            break
        }
        default:
            state = state
    }
    return state
}
```

My approach was creating a newState constant which is identical to the state we receive, make change to the dummy and return it - or in code:

```
const userReducer = (state= {name: null, age: null}, {type, payload}) => {
    const newState = {...state}
    switch(type) {
        case 'CHANGE_VALUE_ONE' : {
            newState.valueOne= payload
            break
        }

        case 'CHANGE_VALUE_TWO' : {
            newState.valueTwo= payload
            break
        }
    }

    return newState
}
```

I think the way i do it is cleaner - if i have a complicated state i can easily change what i need to change without mutating the original state.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With first snippet, you are violating the principle of pure reducer. That means instead of updating the value directly in state, create a new copy of it and do the changes in that.

As per [Doc](https://redux.js.org/introduction/three-principles#changes-are-made-with-pure-functions):

> Reducers are just pure functions that take the previous state and an
>   action, and return the next state. **Remember to return new state
>   objects, instead of mutating the previous state.**

Which you are clearly violating by assigning new value to `state`, here:

`state = {...state, valueOne: payload }`

---

**Note:** Don't forget `const newState = {...state}`, will only create the [shallow copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy), so if you have nested state, this will also violate the principle.

In case of nested state, update it in this way:

```js
var obj = { car: { model: '', num: '' } };

function update() {
  return {
    ...obj,
    car: {
      ...obj.car,
      model: 'abc'
    }
  }
}

console.log('new obj = ', update());

console.log('old obj = ', obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you overcomplicate yourself. Here's a reducer that I use (as an example):

```
import * as types from '../actions/types';
import { Enums } from '../helpers/enums';

const initialState = {
  testState: Enums.command.STOP
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.SET_CREEP_TEST_STATE:
      return {...state, testState: action.testState};
    case types.SET_CREEP_TEST_TIME:
      return {...state, testime: action.testime};
    default: return state;
  }
};
```

It shouldn't be any more complex than that.

Comment: So I shouldn't make a newState const to modify and then return? I should just return object literal with {... state, property: action.data}

Comment: Indeed, all you need to do is return your object with `{...state, etc}`

Answer (score 1):

Your solution isn't immutable, the doc's one is. In more complex cases, I recommend to you use [immer](https://github.com/mweststrate/immer), the lib approach is similar to yours, but you will mutate a copy of the state and then `immer` will merge this copy with the actual state to create a new one. Helps you to work with nested data and bring immutability to reducers.  Your case, with immer:

```
const userReducer = produce(state, draft => {
  switch(type) {
    case 'CHANGE_VALUE_ONE' : {
      draft.valueOne= payload
      break
    }

    case 'CHANGE_VALUE_TWO' : {
      draft.valueTwo= payload
      break
    }
  }
},{name: null, age: null})
```

Answer (score 1):

Always keep the state immutable, use pure function. And there is a performance issue for your approach.

Your approach is immutable. But remember, any dispatched action will go through **all reducers**. That means even the action is not related to your reducer, you still create a new shallow copy of it. It's not necessary. Don't do this

```
// This newState will be created by every action
    const newState = {...state}
    switch(type) {
        case 'CHANGE_VALUE_ONE' : {
            newState.valueOne= payload
            break
        }

        case 'CHANGE_VALUE_TWO' : {
            newState.valueTwo= payload
            break
        }
    }

    return newState
```